# SFTP inbound adapter configuration for multiple remote directory using single adapter and single channel

Tags: spring-integration

I have configured SFTP inbound channel adapter for polling files from SFTP server to local directory in regular interval. I need to set the SFTP inbound channel adapter for 16, such SFTP folder location. How can I achieve it using single adapter and channel.

****Here is my configuration.****

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp-4.1.xsd 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">



         <context:property-placeholder order="0"
        location="classpath:/sftpuser.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
         <context:property-placeholder order="1"
        location="classpath:/sftpfile.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>


    <bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="defaultSftpSessionFactory" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="defaultSftpSessionFactory" 

        class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">

        <property name="host" value="${sftp.host}" />
        <property name="port" value="${sftp.port}" /> 
    <!-- <property name="port" value="22" /> -->
        <property name="user" value="${sftp.username}" />
        <property name="privateKey" value="${private.keyfile}" />
        <property name="privateKeyPassphrase" value="${passphrase}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Inbound channel adapter for SFTP call . with poll facility -->
    <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="sftpInbondAdapter"
        auto-startup="true" channel="sftpReceiveChannel" session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        local-directory="${inboundlocaldir}" remote-directory="${inboundremotedir}"
        auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="false"
        filename-pattern="*.txt" remote-file-separator="/">
     <int:poller fixed-rate="100000" max-messages-per-poll="10" /> 

    </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int:channel id="sftpReceiveChannel">
        <int:queue />
    </int:channel>

</beans>
```

**Updated Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp-4.1.xsd 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

         <context:property-placeholder order="0"
        location="classpath:/sftpuser.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
         <context:property-placeholder order="1"
        location="classpath:/sftpfile.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>


    <bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="defaultSftpSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="defaultSftpSessionFactory" 

        class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">

        <property name="host" value="${sftp.host}" />
        <property name="port" value="${sftp.port}" /> 
        <property name="user" value="${sftp.username}" />
        <property name="privateKey" value="${private.keyfile}" />
        <property name="privateKeyPassphrase" value="${passphrase}" />
    </bean>

        <int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="sftpReceiveChannel"
    expression="'/**/*.txt'">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="10" /> 
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-sftp:outbound-gateway session-factory="defaultSftpSessionFactory"
        request-channel="sftpReceiveChannel"
        command="mget"
        expression="payload"
        local-directory="${inboundlocaldir}"
        reply-channel="resultChannel"
         >
     <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="10" /> 
     </int-sftp:outbound-gateway>
    <int:channel id="sftpReceiveChannel">
        <int:queue />
    </int:channel>

    <int:channel id="resultChannel">
    </int:channel>


</beans>
```

**2nd Update**

```
Sftp-Inboud-context.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp-4.1.xsd 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

         <context:property-placeholder order="0"
        location="classpath:/sftpuser.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
         <context:property-placeholder order="1"
        location="classpath:/sftpfile.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>


    <bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="defaultSftpSessionFactory" />
    </bean>



    <bean id="defaultSftpSessionFactory" 

        class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">

        <property name="host" value="${sftp.host}" />
        <property name="port" value="${sftp.port}" /> 
        <property name="user" value="${sftp.username}" />
        <property name="privateKey" value="${private.keyfile}" />
        <property name="privateKeyPassphrase" value="${passphrase}" />
    </bean>

  <int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="inboundMGetRecursive"
    ref="sftpRemoteFolderParse" method="handle">
   <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>
<bean id= "sftpRemoteFolderParse" class ="com.sftp.SftpRemoteFolderParse"/>

    <int:channel id="output">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="inboundMGetRecursive" >
 <int:queue />
 </int:channel>

<int-sftp:outbound-gateway session-factory="defaultSftpSessionFactory"
    request-channel="inboundMGetRecursive" command="mget" expression="payload"
    command-options="-R" local-directory="C:/Users/Asit/Desktop/asit"
    remote-directory="/u01/IIP/iipuser/test"
    reply-channel="output">

     <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
    </int-sftp:outbound-gateway>

</beans>
```

**SftpRemoteFolderParser.java**

```
package com.sftp;

import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage;

public class SftpRemoteFolderParse {
    public Message<?> handle()
    {
        String dir = "/u01/IIP/iipuser/test";
        Message message =  new GenericMessage<Object>(dir + "*");
        System.out.println("the mesage is" +message);
        return message;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use `<int-sftp:outbound-gateway>` with `MGET` command and `payload` as a `pattern` to retrive appropriate files from all desired remote directories.

That pattern can be provided from the generic `inbound-channel-adapter`:

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="sftpFilesChannel"
    expression="''">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="100000" max-messages-per-poll="10" /> 
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int-sftp:outbound-gateway session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"
        request-channel="sftpFilesChannel"
        command="mget"
        command-options="-R"
        filename-regex="(subDir|.*\.txt)"
        local-directory="/tmp/out"
        reply-channel="resultChannel"/>
```

See the documentation on the matter: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway

Comment: Hi Artem, I have tried with the above configuration seems like resultChannel declaration was missing. Added that in my configuration. But ,no luck. Even if the ssh connection is successful, No file is transferred to local dir, neither the folder structure is not replicated. The updated configuration is added above.

Comment: Can you please give some reference to SFTP pattern to implement here in my configuration

Comment: I updated my answer to be more clear. See the new config variant and docs too.

Comment: I am not able to relate the expression of <int:inbound-channel-adapter > which will return the remote directory structure as message

Comment: Tried with the configuration as discussed with a slight modification. But it seems it is copying all the files from sftp location with out directory structure. The configuration is updated in "2nd update" header

Comment: `remote-directory` isn't in use in case of `MGET`. Need to understand your remote file tree. See our test-case: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-sftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/sftp/outbound. /SftpServerOutboundTests.java#L201. The directory structure is `sftpSource/subSftpSource` and we receive two files from the `sftpSource` dir and one from the `subSftpSource` subdir. So, maybe for your it is just enough to add `/` before `*` for the remote pattern.

Comment: In addition: there is no reason to have `<queue>` channel between `polling` adapter and the target handler. There is just enough do everything within that poller Thread. So, make `inboundMGetRecursive` channel just as direct one - without `<queue>` and that `<poller>` for the `<int-sftp:outbound-gateway>`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69228/discussion-between-asit-roy-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: Need suggestion , how can achieve the pollable capability in this situation, because if I am using mget and mput to send/receive files from SFTP for multiple directory, I am loosing the polling feature which is much required because I want my outbound endpoint to continuiosly listen when the the war is deployed.

Comment: @AsitRoy, would you mind starting a new question with comprehensive details?

Comment: Raised a new question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28128049/making-sftp-outbound-gate-way-pollable-for-mput-operation