# Making SFTP outbound gate way pollable for mput operation

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using spring integration for SFTP operation. I need to poll the files with directory structure from a certain location of SFTP and also put files with directory structure from local directory to certain SFTP location. I have added faking inbound channel adapter fro mget & mput opeation. While running Junit , some junk message files are generated in target SFTP location of mput operation. And ,after war is deployed no file is getting transferred to mget local directory. The mput and mget operation will started once war is deployed in server Please advice the configuration. This queston is in refrence to
[SFTP inbound adapter configuration for multiple remote directory using single adapter and single channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022257/sftp-inbound-adapter-configuration-for-multiple-remote-directory-using-single-ad)

**Sftp-outboundgatewaycontext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int-sftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/sftp/spring-integration-sftp-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">


    <context:property-placeholder order="0"
        location="classpath:/sftpuser.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
    <context:property-placeholder order="1"
        location="classpath:/sftpfile.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true" />
    <bean id="sftpServerConfig" class="com.iux.ieg.sftp.SftpConfigurator" />




    <bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="defaultSftpSessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="defaultSftpSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${sftp.host}" />
        <property name="port" value="${sftp.port}" />
        <property name="user" value="${sftp.username}" />
        <property name="privateKey" value="${private.keyfile}" />
        <property name="privateKeyPassphrase" value="${passphrase}" />
    </bean>

    <int:channel id="outputmget">
        <int:queue />

    </int:channel>

    <int:channel id="outputmput">
        <int:queue />

    </int:channel>

<int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="inboundMGetRecursive"
    expression="''">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="10" /> 
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="inboundMPutRecursive" expression="''">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="10" /> 
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>  





    <int:channel id="inboundMGetRecursive" />

    <int-sftp:outbound-gateway session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        request-channel="inboundMGetRecursive" command="mget" expression="payload"
        mode="REPLACE" command-options="-R"

        local-directory-expression="@sftpServerConfig.targetLocalDirectory+ #remoteDirectory"

        reply-channel="outputmget">
<!-- local-filename-generator-expression="#remoteFileName.replaceFirst('sftpSource', 'localTarget')" -->

    </int-sftp:outbound-gateway>




    <int:channel id="inboundMPutRecursive" />

    <int-sftp:outbound-gateway session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
        request-channel="inboundMPutRecursive" command="mput" command-options="-R"
        auto-create-directory="true" filename-pattern="*.txt" expression="payload"
        local-directory="@SftpServerConfig.mPutLocalDir+'/'"
        remote-directory="sftpTarget" reply-channel="outputmput">

    </int-sftp:outbound-gateway>




</beans>

**Javafile:SftpConfigurator.java**

package com.iux.ieg.sftp;



import java.io.File;

/**

 */
public class SftpConfigurator  {





    private volatile File targetSftpDirectory;

    private volatile File sourceLocalDirectory;

    private volatile File targetLocalDirectory;
    private volatile File mPutLocalDir;

    public File getmPutLocalDir() {
        return mPutLocalDir;
    }



    public void setmPutLocalDir(File mPutLocalDir) {
        this.mPutLocalDir = mPutLocalDir;
    }



    public File getTargetLocalDirectory() {
        return targetLocalDirectory;
    }



    public void setTargetLocalDirectory(File targetLocalDirectory) {
        this.targetLocalDirectory = targetLocalDirectory;
    }



    public File getTargetSftpDirectory() {
        return targetSftpDirectory;
    }



    public void setTargetSftpDirectory(File targetSftpDirectory) {
        this.targetSftpDirectory = targetSftpDirectory;
    }



    public File getSourceLocalDirectory() {
        return sourceLocalDirectory;
    }



    public void setSourceLocalDirectory(File sourceLocalDirectory) {
        this.sourceLocalDirectory = sourceLocalDirectory;
    }







    public SftpConfigurator() {
        this.targetSftpDirectory = new File("/u01/IIP/iipuser/Java/test1") ;
        this.sourceLocalDirectory = new File("D:\\sourceforsftp");
        this.targetLocalDirectory = new File("D:\\sftplocalfolder");
        this.mPutLocalDir=new File("D:\\sourceforsftp");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all clear what you are asking. Phrases like "some junk" are useless. You should be able to debug this application by turning on DEBUG logging and track the messages through the flow.

Answer (score 0):

`MPUT` is end-user operation. What is the reason of `inbound-channel-adapter` for such an operation? You should send `local directory` as a message `payload` to `PUT` all files to the SFTP. Right now your config does not make sence.

Comment: But, how can I make the MPUT operation a  pollable one

Comment: Please, be more specific: what are you going to poll? As I said: an argument for the `MPUT` message is `directory`. `local-directory` is ignored for the `MPUT` in the `<int-sftp:outbound-gateway>`. So, your `poller` should produce that directory, if its contents is changed periodically.

Comment: Hi , Artem, looking at the JUnit u mentioned in https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/tree/master/spring-integration-sftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/sftp/outbound, I have configured the "inboundMgettRecursive" channel to receive the files from sftp directory. And written a Junit to receive the files mentioning dir of SFTP in message like this.inboundMGetRecursive.send(new GenericMessage<Object>(dir + "/")). But I do  not know how to set the SFTP directory in the xml configuraion file from where I will get the files. Please suggest

Comment: `remote-directory` is ignored in case of `MGET`. You should specify the remote `root` pattern in the send message and use `expression` to derivative that remote path pattern.